# utilizar objetos literales

Tags: javascript

tengo un ejercicio a resolver

En base a las definiciones técnicas tomadas con el equipo deberás declarar la variable autos. Esta debe contener los siguientes vehículos:

El primer auto es un Ford Fiesta Azul, del 2019, con 200 kilómetros, cuyo precio es 150000, disponible en 12 cuotas, con la patente APL123 que no está vendido.
El segundo auto es un Toyota Corolla Blanco, del 2019, 0 kilómetros, cuyo precio es 100000, disponible en 14 cuotas, con la patente JJK116 que no está vendido.
Cada auto debe tener los siguientes atributos: marca, modelo, precio, km, color, cuotas, anio, patente, vendido.
Y mi codigo es este

```
function Autos(marca, modelo, precio, km, color, cuotas, anio, patente, vendido){
    this.marca=marca
    this.modelo=modelo
    this.precio=precio
    this.km=km
    this.color=color
    this.cuotas=cuotas
    this.anio=anio
    this.patente=patente
    this.vendido=vendido

}

let autos =new Autos ["Ford", "Fiesta",150000,200,"Azul",12,2019,"APL123",false]
new Autos["Toyota","Corolla",100000,0,"Blanco",14,2019,"jjk116",false]
module.exports=autos
```

pero me tira error
Autos[("Ford" , "Fiesta" , 150000 , 200 , "Azul" , 12 , 2019 , "APL123" , false)] is not a constructor

Comment: `[]` declara un array... el constructor es un método y se llama como cualquier otro método, con paréntesis: `new Autos(blablabla)`. De hecho.... en donde lo has declarado le has puesto los paréntesis, no entiendo qué te hizo pensar luego que tenías que ponerle corchetes y no paréntesis... -> `function Autos(marca....)`

Comment: @Benito-B me sigue generando error

Comment: let auto =new Autos ("Ford", "Fiesta",150000,200,"Azul",12,2019,"APL123",false)

Answer (score 2):

Aqui hay una confusión con el `this` por un lado (mia y supongo que de otros también) y sobre como se crean instancias por otro. Al principio me confundió el uso del `this` porque no es una forma habitual de crear objetos, aqui la aclaración.

El `this` dentro de una función, y ejecutado con un navegador es `window` (en nodejs es otra cosa pero igualmente es global), al hacer `this.una_variable` estamos agregando `una_variable` al scope global.

```js
function unaFuncion(un_valor) {

  console.log(this === window); // <-- true

  this.una_variable = un_valor; // <-- Es scope es window

}

unaFuncion("algun_valor"); // <-- Lo llamamos como una función


console.log(una_variable);
```

**Pero...** al invocar la función con `new` el `this` cambia totalmente el sentido y la función se comporta como un constructor de manera que devuelve un objeto. Pero la función debe llamarse como se llamaría un constructor, `new Una_clase(parametro1, parametro1)`.

```js
function Autos(marca, modelo, precio, km, color, cuotas, anio, patente, vendido){
    this.marca=marca
    this.modelo=modelo
    this.precio=precio
    this.km=km
    this.color=color
    this.cuotas=cuotas
    this.anio=anio
    this.patente=patente
    this.vendido=vendido

}

let auto1 = new Autos("Ford", "Fiesta",150000,200,"Azul",12,2019,"APL123",false);
let auto2 = new Autos("Toyota","Corolla",100000,0,"Blanco",14,2019,"jjk116",false);

const autos = [auto1,auto2];

console.log(autos)
```

Para que cada objeto auto esté dentro de un array autos tienes que insertar cada auto en autos, sea al declararlo o haciendo `push`.

Comment: @MiguelTraiano me di cuenta que no interpreté bien la pregunta, aqui te dejo una actualización que creo que aclara el panorama.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que buscas es una clase. Lo que has hecho es una función llamada Autos.

Una clase se crea de la siguiente manera:

```
class Rectangulo {
   constructor(ancho, alto) {
      this.ancho = ancho
      this.alto = alto
  }
}
```

Una vez que hecho esto, puedes crear una instancia de la siguiente manera:

```
rectangulo1 = new Rectangulo(4, 5)
```

Suponiendo que no tengas mucho conocimiento sobre programación orientada a objetos, intentaré explicarte un par de cosas con ejemplos. Te tomará un tiempo asimilarlo.

Una clase es una estructura con cosas que tiene en común algo. Por ejemplo, transporte, auto, forma, polígono, persona, etc. Si buscas una analogía, podrías considerarla como un molde.

Instanciar es crear un objeto de la clase indicada. Por ejemplo, si tienes una clase persona, cada vez que instancies, estarás creando una persona nueva y única.

Puedes obtener más información [aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes).

Answer (score 1):

Tu constructor es básicamente una función que recibe parámetros, y luego abajo define una estructura que se utilizará cada vez que hagas un new autos(valor1, valor2, valor3).
Entonces luego usarás por ejemplo:

```
const auto = new Autos("Toyota","Corolla",100000,0,"Blanco",14,2019,"jjk116",false)
```

Aquí arriba le pasamos los datos como parametros, separados por "," como a cualquier función.

Ahora si consultas por auto, tendrás:

```
{marca: 'Toyota', modelo: 'Corolla', precio: 100000, km: 0, color: 'Blanco', …}
```

El constructor básicamente lo estás utilizando como un "molde".

Answer (score 1):

```
        // inicio la variables
        let autos =[];
        let cantidadAutos = 0;
        let cantidadRegistrados = 0;

        // Ahora la funcion constructora
        function Auto (marca, modelo, annio) {
            this.marca = marca;
            this.modelo = modelo;
            this.annio = annio;
        }

        //Cuantos autos va a registrar
        cantidadAutos = prompt('Cuantos autos desea registrar? ');

        // Aqui el ciclo para carga del usuario

        while (cantidadRegistrados < cantidadAutos) {
            // Defino variables scope local
            let marca = prompt('Marca: ');
            let modelo = prompt('Modelo: ');
            let annio = prompt('Annio');

            //Paso las variables de scope local a la funcion constructora
            var autoNuevo = new Auto(marca, modelo, annio);

            // Agrego el auto a mi arreglo de autos
            autos.unshift(autoNuevo);

            // increento la cantidad de autos registrados en 1
            cantidadRegistrados++;
        }

        /* Retorno en consola el arreglo de los autos
        registrados por el usuario */
        console.log(autos);
```