# ¿Como puedo definir parametros de un Canvas usando una Funcion?

Tags: javascript, canvas, parametros, motor-de-juego, funcion

Para empezar quiero aclarar de que quiero hacer un "Motor de Creacion de VideoJuegos" hecho con JavaScript nativo, como una libreria, estoy recien empezando y quiero hacer una funcion "SetCanvas" que tome los siguientes argumentos:

1. id: La id del Canvas en el que se va a trabajar.
2. width: El ancho del canvas que se va a definir.
3. height: El alto del canvas que se va a definir.
4. ctx: El contexto que se va a Emplear para trabajar.

Este es el Codigo de la Libreria:

```
    function SetCanvas(id,width, height,ctx) {
    var c = document.getElementById(this.id);
    c.width = this.width;
    c.height = this.height;
    var ctx = c.getContext(this.ctx);
}
```

Y lo enlazo a este codigo para Probarlo:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Mi Juego</title>
    <script src="GameMake.js"></script>
    </head>
    
    <body>
    <canvas id="c" style="border:1px solid black"></canvas>
    <script>
    SetCanvas("c", 200, 200, "2d");
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

El problema aqui es que cuando lo ejecuto me da un error diciendome esto:

```
    > Uncaught TypeError: c.getContext is not a function
at SetCanvas (GameMake.js:5)
at MiJuego.html:11
```

SetCanvas @ GameMake.js:5
(anonymous) @ MiJuego.html:11

(GameMake.js es la Libreria y MiJuego.html es la prueba)

Que alguien me corrija si es que lo hice mal, muchas gracias!

Comment: primero necesitas entender el [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) ya que estas haciendo referencia a `this.id`  que no existes! existe es `id` fuera de que solicitas es `tagName` no `id`

Comment: Estás mezclando clases y funciones. Te servirá darle una mirada a esta otra pregunta https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/502182/169744 . Una vez tengas claro qué es lo que quieres hacer, modifica la pregunta.

Comment: muchas gracias y perdon por ese error, pasa que como no encontraba la solucion buscaba de muchas formas, y me despiste, muchas gracias lo tendre en cuenta